# Python: creating a comma separated string from a query

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a query

```
 messages = Message.objects.all()
```

I want to create a Create a comma separated string of all numbers from message.number

This is what I have tried:

```
number = ""
for obj in messages:
     number = number + "," + obj.number
```

How can I do this? PS this string can be VERY long over 400,000 numbers!

Comment: Are you going to write this back out to a file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `join()`:

```
",".join(str(msg.number) for msg in Message.objects.all())
```

Also, since you have a large queryset, consider splitting your results into chunks using a queryset iterator. For more info see:

- [Why is iterating through a large Django QuerySet consuming massive amounts of memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4222176/why-is-iterating-through-a-large-django-queryset-consuming-massive-amounts-of-me)
- [Limiting Memory Use in a *Large* Django QuerySet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856882/limiting-memory-use-in-a-large-django-queryset)
- http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1949/
- http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1170/

Comment: This won't work if `msg.number` is actually a _number_, better cast it to string first; and you also have extra `( )` in there.

Answer (score 1):

Use [str.join](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
number = ','.join(messages)
```